# Excel: Merge two tables based on one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two Excel 2007 sheets A,B with the same columns.

B contains less rows, but has a column with updated data (i.e. data in this column is newer than in the same column in A). I want to take every row in B, find the corresponding row in A (through a unique key, f.e. column C1) and update the value of the column with the updated version from B.

Before

```
A           B   
C1 C2 C3    C1 C2 C3
1  2  3     1  2  99
2  6  7
```

After

```
A           B   
C1 C2 C3    C1 C2 C3
1  2  99    1  2  99
2  6  7
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) to initially populate the data, then copy values onto a new sheet to remove the reference.

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well. In German versions of Excel, the function is called [SVERWEIS](http://office.microsoft.com/de-de/excel-help/sverweis-HP005209335.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Vlookup or the If functions